# how to add validations on the textboxes in edit/update data mode?

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, edit

i have a add product function. after adding those, it will then be viewed. along with the view function is a delete and update link. it works perfectly fine. When i click on the update, textboxes are visible for editing. again, it works fine. but what i want to do is to add validations to it. like if the value should only contain a number, then it will restrict any characters to that update. here is my code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");
        //TextBox txtname=(TextBox)gr.cell[].control[];
        TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        TextBox textDesc = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
        TextBox textQuantity = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
        TextBox textProductPrice = (TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
        //TextBox textadd = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtadd");
        //TextBox textc = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtc");
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        conn.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM detail", conn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Products set ProductName='" + textName.Text + "',ProductDescription='" + textDesc.Text + "',ProductQuantity='" + textQuantity.Text + "',ProductPrice ='" + textProductPrice.Text + "'where ProductID='" + userid + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        gvbind();
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

any ideas on what can i do to add validations. the reason for this is that when i try to input for example "abc" to the

```
TextBox textQuantity = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
```

it gives me an error that it cannot be converted. please help. thanks!

Comment: Please try to tag with the correct language...

Answer (score 0):

You have to find control on each of the gridview row
Below is an example

```
    TextBox textQuantity = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBoxId");

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textQuantity .Text))
                    {
                      //Validation failed
                        return;
                    }
```

Comment: and then? how do i validate sir?

Comment: just check if the Text property is not empty or null. This will be now your textbox of the specific row of the grid. Do what you want. :)

Comment: can you give me an example sir? i want to validate for example, only numbers are allowed?

Comment: by the way, these textboxes are visible when i click on the update function sir

Comment: Ive edited the answer with validation. Visibility of the textboxes does not matter for validation.